# Arduino I²C slave onReceive fails

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, i2c, raspberry-pi2

I'm currently having some problems with my Arduino and my Raspberry Pi 2.

I set up a working I²C connection between the Arduino and the Pi. I configured the Arduino as slave.

Some simple tests worked. But when I keep using the Arduino for about 5 minutes (actual time is random) over I²C the function I registered with `Wire.onReceive` stops being called. The Arduino keeps sending values on request but seems to completly ignore any data being send to it.

What I have tested so far:

- Removing all pin writes and reads on the Arduino
- Increasing the delay between two requests from the Pi. This just seems to increase the time it is working. Still fails eventually
- Frequently reregistering the functions

Here is the code on the Arduino:

```cpp
#include <Wire.h>

const byte ADDRESS = 0x4E;
const byte FLAG_PWM = 0x80;

byte states[22] = {OUTPUT, OUTPUT, OUTPUT, OUTPUT, OUTPUT, OUTPUT, OUTPUT, OUTPUT, OUTPUT, OUTPUT, OUTPUT, OUTPUT, OUTPUT, OUTPUT, OUTPUT, OUTPUT, OUTPUT, OUTPUT, OUTPUT, OUTPUT, OUTPUT, OUTPUT};
byte request;

void setup() {
  Wire.begin(ADDRESS);
  Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent);
  Wire.onRequest(requestEvent);
}

void loop() {
  delay(100);
}

// At some point this function isn't called anymore. (request doesn't change)
void receiveEvent(int howMany) {
  byte byteIN = Wire.read();
  boolean pwm = byteIN & FLAG_PWM;

  byteIN &= ~FLAG_PWM;

  if (byteIN > 21)
    return;

  if (howMany == 1) {
    request = byteIN;

    if (states[byteIN] != INPUT)
      pinMode(byteIN, INPUT);
  } else if (howMany == 2) {
    if (states[byteIN] != OUTPUT)
        pinMode(byteIN, OUTPUT);

    byte value = Wire.read();

    // Disabling this does not help
    if (pwm)
      analogWrite(byteIN, value);
    else
      digitalWrite(byteIN, value);
  }
}

// This function keeps working after the other failed.
void requestEvent() {
  if (request < A0) {
    // Disabling this does not help
    byte value = digitalRead(request);

    Wire.write(&value, 1);
  } else {
    // Disabling this does not help
    int value = analogRead(request);

    Wire.write((char*)&value, 2);
  }
}
```

*Right now I can't access the code on the Pi. But if needed I can post it here.*

The Pi is requesting a single read about every 20ms.

I'm running out of ideas what might be wrong...

Comment: Can you post your part of the code that deals with i2c ? Does it start working again if you reboot both the devices ? I'm assuming that you used level shifter and everything since Rpi is a 3v3 device and arduino is 5v device.

Comment: @dastaan It already works when I reset the Arduino.

Comment: @dastaan Yes. I am using a level shifter.

Comment: @BrainStone Did you ever get anywhere? I'm also using a pi to talk to an Arduino via I2C and onReceive() stops being called after 30 seconds or so.

Comment: @Bort yes I eventually solved it. But I don't remember what I did. And I can access the code at the moment. If I remember correctly a sleep was too short or missing.

Comment: @BrainStone You mean delay()? I don't have any delay(). You're saying I need one?

Comment: @Bort yes. Try that.

Comment: @Bort do you have one in loop? There should be one for sure.

Comment: @BrainStone I can't put a large delay in my loop because my code is running servos that need to react quickly. I tried putting in `delay(200)` in my loop()  just to see what would happen and it still didn't help.

Comment: @Bort I mean something like 2-5

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130342/discussion-between-bort-and-brainstone).

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert, but there is a function in Wire that checks if there are available something to read:

```
String DecodeUri()
{
  String ret = "";
  while (1 < Wire.available())
  {
     ret += (char)Wire.read();
  }
    ret += (char)Wire.read();
 return ret;
}
```

Apart you can check howMany to check if you can read.

And another weird thing I have is that if I use a battery with not too much power the I2C goes weird.